# RESTful URI structure for fetching the same form in different modes

Tags: forms, rest

I am designing an application that needs to dynamically load a form via an AJAX request.  There should be three "modes": "create user", "update user", and "view user" (readonly).

However in all three cases, I am **fetching** a resource - thus these should all be `GET` requests (I'm not talking about the URIs I use to actually *submit* the form).  They're all (virtually) the same form, so I consider them to be the same resource.

It seems to me that I could do something like:

```
GET /forms/users                     // Get a blank form for creating a new user
GET /forms/users/u/1?mode="view"     // Get a form that shows info for user 1
GET /forms/users/u/1?mode="update"   // Get a form that allows updating info for user 1
```

Or something like:

```
GET /forms/users                      // Get a blank form for creating a new user
GET /forms/users?id=1&mode="view"     // Get a form that shows info for user 1
GET /forms/users?id=1&mode="update"   // Get a form that allows updating info for user 1
```

Would either of these be "correct" according to REST?  Or should I do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL should be describing the resource, something like:

```
GET /forms/info/user/new               // form to create a new user
GET /forms/info/user/1                 // form to view user 1 info
```

You can pass a query string parameter to make the form updatable. Ex:

```
GET /forms/info/user/1?updatable=true
```

But that sounds like a browser, not a REST concern. REST is for communicating with API, and updating the user info would just require a PUT verb instead of the GET.

So just add some javascript code to make the form editable by a user.

Comment: The server gets to decide whether or not the form is editable, not the client.  But, I like the `new` pattern - very explicit.

Comment: Then why do you need a different URL for that scenario? Just let the server generate the form the proper way based on security (or whatever drives that).

Comment: Well, the client still gets to "ask" for an editable form.  The server must approve the request based on authorization rules.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GET` for `"view user"` operation and to get the user properties, use the `PUT` for the `"create user"` operation  and for `"update user"` operation  use the `PATCH`. This is the way I used to do.

It's an unusual practice to get a form from the REST API, having the client side application to show entire forms fetching from the API.

In your case you're right I guess, the only alternative I can see is

```
GET /forms/user/add           // Get a blank form for creating a new user
GET /forms/user/view/1     // Get a form that shows info for user 1
GET /forms/user/update/1  // Get a form that allows updating info for user 1
```

Comment: No, you misunderstand.  I'm not talking about the URIs for actually *submitting* the form.  I'm talking about the URIs to *fetch* the form as a standalone resource.